# trying to use fwrite to write integer to binary file but nothing comes up in C

Tags: c, binaryfiles, fwrite

I have this code which has int count. I have tried everything but nothing shows up in the binary file.

```c
fwrite(&count, sizeof(count), 1, stdout);
```

For example I have this same fwrite but for a char and it works fine:

```c
fwrite(&prevc, sizeof(prevc), 1, stdout);
```

With these two fwrites only the char one writes anything to the terminal.
How do I get the integer to show up to the stdout also?

[image: hexdump]

Comment: Your integer is binary data, not text.

Comment: The terminal is a text-device, it will only display printable characters. If the value of `count` isn't corresponding to something printable, nothing will (seem to) be printed.

Comment: And what is your goal? What is the underlying problem you need to solve? Why are you using the `fwrite` function to write to the terminal rather than the much more common `printf`?

Comment: I'm trying to write to a file with fwrite using linux > pipe through terminal and that is why 
 I use stdout. But the problem is that I can't get any of the integers to show up in the binary file only "." in their place.  The char works fine even with binary file.

Comment: Then you perhaps look at the binary file using a text tool. Do a [hexdump](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/hexdump.1.html) to see the actual data.

Comment: I use addon on vscode called hexdump for vscode which shows the file in the right format. I put image on the original post for that.

Comment: That hexdump shows the integer values `3`, `2`, `3`, `1`, `2` and `1` before and between the letters. For example the sequence `02 00 00 00` is the 32-bit little [endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) representation of the integer `2`. To repeat what @tkausl says, the integer is written in its raw binary form, not as text.

Comment: If you want to get human readable output instead of binary data, you should use `fprintf` instead of `fwrite` to write your text.

Comment: Try the `int` value 7955784 and see what you get. The things to learn are left as an exercise to you.

Comment: By the way, for future questions please take the time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please learn how to create a proper [mre] to show us.